# Refreshing a QSqlDatabase object's settings

Tags: c++, qt

I have a Qt application which (essentially) creates a `QMYSQL` database connection using `QSqlDatabase`, creates a `gridPopulator` instance to populate a `QTableView` with (obviously) data from the database. It seems pretty simple, but I have a preferences dialog, which is able to change the database connection settings. So, if the settings are accepted from within the preferences dialog, my application has to use `gridPopulator::refresh()` to repopulate the `QTableView`. I tried my best to explain the process in the diagram below.

[image]

The program I currently have is able to change the settings of the database object like so:

```
preferences p; p.read();
QSqlDatabase databaseConnection = QSqlDatabase::database("SCHEDULE_DATABASE");

databaseConnection.setHostName(p.database->server_addr);
databaseConnection.setUserName(p.database->username);
databaseConnection.setPassword(p.database->password);
databaseConnection.setDatabaseName(p.database->database_name);
databaseConnection.setPort(p.database->serverPort);
```

It seems, though, that this is not enough to actually **refresh** the database connection. How to properly create this *refresh* process?

Comment: Have you closed the database connection before setting the new values? I typically close the existing connection, then set the values and reopen it again. Could you please provide the implementation of the refresh method?

Comment: I am not in front of my computer right now, but as soon as I will be, of course, I will post everything needed.

Answer (score 1):

You need to close() and open() the connection after changing the settings. This is written in the documentation too.

Comment: I was just about to answer my question.